# SQLiteDatabase updates only when the application is reopened

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an android app that successfully inserts data in my database when I click a marker in the map.

I have an activity that updates its info(column) in the database. It doesn't update on my first attempt but when I close, exit the app, run it again and update the info again, it successfully updates so I believe my code is right. What would the problem?

Process:

1st open

- place marker
- onInfoWindowClick starts new activityForResult
- fill up fields
- save (button)
- return values to update a row
- doesn't update

re-open

- when an existing marker is clicked, fill up fields, it updates when saved
- when a new marker is placed, fill up fields, doesn't update (means need to reopen again)

Call to update:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_TITLE, newReminder);
cv.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_MONTH, mm_final);
cv.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_DAY, dd_final);
cv.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_YEAR, yy_final);

getContentResolver().update(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, cv, "lat=? AND lng=?", new String[] {location_lat, location_lng});
```

LocationContentProvider.java:

```
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs){
    int count;
    count = mLocationsDB.update(values, selection, selectionArgs);
    return count;
}
```

LocationsDB.java:

```
public int update(ContentValues contentValues, String where, String[] whereArgs){
    int cnt = mDB.update(DATABASE_TABLE, contentValues, where, whereArgs);
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: Please show some code that illustrates the issue and no more than necessary.

Comment: Where did you put the update function?

Comment: @m170897017 the update call is placed in onActivityResult()

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I included the code. But like I said, it updates when the app is reopened and not when there is a new inserted value

Comment: Are you certain that the database doesn't update? Or is the problem that the data isn't shown in your views? How are you displaying the data?

Comment: What is `LocationsDB`? Does it extend `SQLiteOpenHelper`? If so, you don't need to implement your own `update()` function as the super class already provides it. In fact, the only two methods you should have in `LocationsDB` are `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes I am certain that it is not updating. LocationsDB extends LocationContentProvider.

Comment: For all of the code you have given, please show the enclosing class and declarations for any pertinent member variables.

Comment: Also please describe how you know that the database isn't updating. Did you connect to the device with abd? Did you open the.db file with sqlite3?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your SQLite database **has** changed, but the `ContentResolver` does not know it. In your the `update()` method of your `ContentProvider`, add this line of code:

```
this.getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

This notifies the `ContentResolver` that a change has occurred. The resolver will then update an UI components that depend on the data.